# How to remove all elements from NSTreeController with NSOutlineController

Tags: cocoa, binding, nsarraycontroller, nstreecontroller, removeall

I am using `NSTreeController` with `NSOutlineController` to display contents in 1parent-1child hierarchy.
My structure is like this:

- parent

- child

- parent

- child

Now when user press a refresh button, I want to remove all the nodes and refill it again.

```
[[treeController arrangedObjects] removeAllItems];
[[treeController arrangedObjects] removeAllObjects];
```

but nothings seems to be working.

I guess binging `NSTreeController` with `NSArrayController` should help but I really don't know steps to bind -`NSArrayController`-`NSTreeController`-`NSOutlineController`.

Answer (score 2):

I do it all the time with unbound lists.

Simple to clear the list:

[treeController setContent:nil];

Comment: I found this makes it not possible to Add objects later though to the Controller...

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for the `content` property:

> The value of this property can be an array of objects, or a single root object. The default value is nil.

If your content is an array (presumably an `NSMutableArray`), then

```
[treeController.content removeAllObjects];
```

would be appropriate. Setting it to `nil` removes the underlying container. If your content is a single object, then

```
treeController.content = nil;
```

is the correct choice.